# java : convert current system time in mongo supported date format

Tags: java, mongodb, datetime

I need to use a query in mongodb which compares the current system date and time with the value of endTime key.

```
Date date   =   new Date();
System.out.println("Current Date : "+date);
db.collection.findOne({endTime: "Tue Oct 08 14:08:41 IST 2013"});
```

which returns null.
But in actual, the result exist for the given date

```
db.collection.findOne({endTime: ISODate("2013-10-08T14:08:41Z")});
{
    "_id" : NumberLong(45),
    "endTime" : ISODate("2013-10-08T18:30:00Z"),
    "publish" : true,
    "startTime" : ISODate("2013-09-30T09:53:14Z")
}
```

Comment: Did you try and google "formatting date java". **And why not?** Also, your code won't actually compile in Java... This `db.collection.findOne({endTime: "Tue Oct 08 14:08:41 IST 2013"});` is not valid Java syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not correct. If you want to query date on MongoDB shell then use the following command.

```
> var date = new Date();
> db.myObject.find({endTime:{$lt:date}});
```

If you want to run query on java then use the following code:

```
DBCollection coll = ...

DBObject ltQuery = new BasicDBObject("$lt", new Date());
DBObject obj = coll.findOne(new BasicDBObject("endTime", ltQuery));
if (obj != null) {
    // Get data from DBObject
}
```